# mybatis insert and update index out of bounds error

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I am having a mybatis issue with a update call.  For some reason I am getting a index out of bounds exception:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
      The index 1 is out of range.
```

This makes me think that parameter is a map or collection of some sort.  However I pass it a single object which i use the `#{}` syntax to get the proporties of.  I then make a direct update call.

```
<update id="updateFactory" statementType="CALLABLE"
    parameterType="WorkOrder">
    UPDATE wo
    SET factory = '#{factory}'
    WHERE work_order = '#{work_order}'  
</update>
```

I know that the parameters match with the getters and setters but it still seems to be an issue with it treating the type alias WorkOrder as a collection.  (it seems it gets the first index (0) but fails on the next (1st index).

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Why do you use callable statement? This might be the issue as callable statement is needed to invoke stored procedure and requires special syntax. And your suggestion regarding first index is not correct as in jdbc parameters indices start from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
<update id="updateFactory" 
        parameterType="WorkOrder">
    UPDATE wo
    SET factory = '#{factory}'
    WHERE work_order = '#{work_order}'  
</update>
```